# Weird shape when I use randomized search cv

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am learning `RandomizedSearchCV` with a toy example. Suppose that I want to build a linear model y = ax + b. I wrote a custom sklearn estimator that looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np
# import the base estimator
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
class testEstimator(BaseEstimator,RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, alpha=1, beta=0):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        mu = np.ones((len(X)))
        for ii in range(len(X)):
            mu[ii] = self.alpha*X[ii] + self.beta
        self.mu_ = mu
        return self
    def predict(self, X):
        try: 
            getattr(self,"mu_")
        except:
            raise RuntimeError("You must train classifer before predicting data!")
        return self.mu_
    def score(self, X, y):
        print("y: ", y)
        print("mu: ", self.mu_)
        return np.dot(y - self.predict(X), y - self.predict(X))/len(X)
```

Then, I need to test this.

```
# temp estimator
tempEs = testEstimator()
# temp params grid
params_grid_temp = {'alpha': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 'beta': [0,1,2,3,4]}
# test randomizedSearchCV
temp = RandomizedSearchCV(tempEs, params_grid_temp)
# define X,y
X = range(10)
y = np.dot(2, range(10)) + 4
# fit model
temp.fit(X,y)
```

However, I got the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-72a46fdf9098> in <module>
      9 y = np.dot(2, range(10)) + 4
     10 # fit model
---> 11 temp.fit(X,y)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    734                 return results
    735 
--> 736             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    737 
    738         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1527     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1528         """Search n_iter candidates from param_distributions"""
-> 1529         evaluate_candidates(ParameterSampler(
   1530             self.param_distributions, self.n_iter,
   1531             random_state=self.random_state))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    706                               n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits))
    707 
--> 708                 out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator),
    709                                                        X, y,
    710                                                        train=train, test=test,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1027             # remaining jobs.
   1028             self._iterating = False
-> 1029             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1030                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1031 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    845                 return False
    846             else:
--> 847                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    848                 return True
    849 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    763         with self._lock:
    764             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 765             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    766             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    767             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    250         # change the default number of processes to -1
    251         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 252             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    253                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    254 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    250         # change the default number of processes to -1
    251         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 252             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    253                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    254 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    558     else:
    559         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
--> 560         test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    561         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    562         if return_train_score:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    605         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    606     else:
--> 607         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
    608 
    609     error_msg = ("scoring must return a number, got %s (%s) "

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py in __call__(self, estimator, *args, **kwargs)
     88                                       *args, **kwargs)
     89             else:
---> 90                 score = scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
     91             scores[name] = score
     92         return scores

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py in _passthrough_scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
    370 def _passthrough_scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs):
    371     """Function that wraps estimator.score"""
--> 372     return estimator.score(*args, **kwargs)
    373 
    374 

<ipython-input-7-0c2138d9bf96> in score(self, X, y)
     20         print("y: ", y)
     21         print("mu: ", self.mu_)
---> 22         return np.dot(y - self.predict(X), y - self.predict(X))/len(X)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (8,)
```

I figured out (2,) means the size of `y` and (8,) means the size of `self.mu_`. How does this happen? They are supposed to be 10.

Comment: what is printed in screen?

Comment: The value of the actual `y` and predicted `y`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem. Your predict method is totally wrong. It must return predicted value instead of returning `mu_`.

```
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.alpha*X + self.beta
```

That's it. You can also optimize code in your `fit` method

Comment: Thanks Tuqay! So you mean my 'fit' function should actually be 'predict' and 'fit' should return nothing?

Comment: I didn't mean that. `fit` method must return the estimator itself. I meant that you can optimize your code. To be honest, I see that your `fit`  function isn't correct, but I am not that qualified to fix that. I am sorry, that's all I can do

Comment: OK. I see what you mean. I actually made a typo on my last comment. I know `fit` should always return self. I meant `fit` in my estimator should do nothing.

Comment: Again. Thanks for following this up Tuqay! You helped me a lot. Actually, this is my assignment at work. Do you think you can ask your friends who are expert on my question? I am totally new to writing a customized estimator. What is worse, my deadline is approaching so it would be really fantastic if I can get some guidance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't further help you. But you can ask a new question. But  try to show, what have you done and be specific about your question